# android timepicker on cancel

Tags: android, dialog, timepicker

I use standart android's timepicker:

```
...
showDialog(TIMEPICKER);
...
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            //code;     
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIMEPICKER:
    return new TimePickerDialog(this,mTimeSetListener, 0, 0, true);
    }
    return null;
    }
```

everything is fine, but how can i catch cancel button to perform some code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setOnCancelListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnCancelListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener%29) or try even the setOnDismissListener.